# Can Zathura show pdf bookmarks generated by other pdf programs?

Tags: pdf, zathura, poppler

I have pdf ebooks with extensive (nested) bookmarks that are visible in all my other pdf readers (e.g. evince, foxitreader).

However, when I open said files in Zathura, running `blist` gives:

> No bookmarks available

I get the same result with both the mupdf and the poppler plugins. I am running Zathura on Arch linux, and installed it (both versions, mupdf and poppler) from the Arch official repositories.

Is there anyway to see these preexisting bookmarks, or does Zathura only recognize its own bookmarks?

Comment: Just FYI, what you call bookmarks here, zathura calls the "index"; it is the thing generally used as a table-of-contents menu inside PDFs.  zathura's "bookmarks" are like actual bookmarks: a user can use `bmark` to create a bookmark while reading a PDF and view the bookmarks they create later using `blist`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I posted the same question in the Arch Linux forums and got the following embarrassingly simple [answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1761793#p1761793).

Just hit the "tab" button. You can then navigate the bookmarks with h, j, k, l (l and h drill down and collapse nested bookmarks, respectively).

Comment: And how do you go to a bookmark?

Comment: @71GA highlight the bookmark and press enter